# How to disable sub-pixel aliasing for fonts

Tags: raspbian-stretch, xorg, pixel

On running desktop environment pixel is hard readable all small texts, because default font sub-pixel aliasing don't correspond with my screen.

So, how to disable font sub-pixel aliasing for all fonts?
or how to change it to `B-G-R-W` pattern?